# Getting error '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'ascii_lower'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_frequencies(filename: str) -> None:
    '''
    1. Open a text file.
    2. Read all its lines.
    3. Turn each line to lower case (use .lower() )
    4. Ignore any letters that are not a-z (use string.ascii_lower)
    5. Compute the counts for each letter
    6. Go through all the letters,
    6. Compute the frequency of each letter.
    7. Print the letter, and its frequency.

    Parameter:
    ---------
    filename: the name of the text file
    '''

    text = open(filename, 'r')
    letters = text.ascii_lower
    for i in text:
      text_lower = i.lower()
      text_nospace = text_lower.replace(" ", "")
      text_nopunctuation = text_nospace.strip(string.punctuation)
      for a in letters:
          if a in text_nopunctuation:
              num = text_nopunctuation.count(a)
              print(a, num)
```

Here is the Traceback I got when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/MyPython/Code/StackOverflow-Questions/get_frequencies-Broken.py", line 28, in <module>
    get_frequencies('test1.txt')
  File "C:/MyPython/Code/StackOverflow-Questions/get_frequencies-Broken.py", line 18, in get_frequencies
    letters = text.ascii_lower
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'ascii_lower'
```

Comment: While it is okay to ask questions about homework, there should be at least one attempt to solve the task and a specific question about it. At least the question should be well formatted. You can find help here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is not clear about the error? `text` is a file object and it doesn't have a `ascii_lower` attribute. You probably meant `string.ascii_lower`. Maybe if you would share some context and actually ask a question, we would be able to help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to import string, and you need to assign string.ascii_lowercase to the letter variable.

Here's a working version:

```
import string

def get_frequencies(filename: str) -> None:
    '''
    1. Open a text file.
    2. Read all its lines.
    3. Turn each line to lower case (use .lower() )
    4. Ignore any letters that are not a-z (use string.ascii_lower)
    5. Compute the counts for each letter
    6. Go through all the letters,
    6. Compute the frequency of each letter.
    7. Print the letter, and its frequency.

    Parameter:
    ---------
    filename: the name of the text file
    '''
    text = open(filename, 'r')
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    for i in text:
      text_lower = i.lower()
      text_nospace = text_lower.replace(" ", "")
      text_nopunctuation = text_nospace.strip(string.punctuation)
      for a in letters:
          if a in text_nopunctuation:
              num = text_nopunctuation.count(a)
              print(a, num)
```